# Is there something wrong with my accessibility?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've followed tutorials and created a simple example of passing variables down through access levels.

I have a `Response.Write()` to try and display a string that I have passed down through a derived class.

The code compiles and Visual Studio comes up with no errors, however when I run the application (ASP.NET Web Application), nothing is displayed on the page.

```
    using System; 
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Collections.Generic; 
    using System.Linq; 
    using System.Web; 
    using System.Web.UI; 
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

 public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
 {
     public class FirstClass
     {
         protected int x;
     }

     public class SecondClass : FirstClass
     {
         static void main()
         {
             SecondClass b = new SecondClass();
             b.x = 10;
             string xstring = (b.x.ToString());               
         }     
     }            
     private void createString(string xstring)
     {
        Response.Write(xstring);    
     } 
  }
```

Is this a problem with the access levels? Or have I not passed `xstring` down to `createString()` correctly?

Or is it also possible that the code functions, but that `xstring` is somehow a `null`?

Comment: Where are you calling the createString method?

Comment: Where is your Page_Load? A combination of `Console App` & `Web App`, Please refer some good tutorials!

Comment: argh! all rookie errors! Thanks for pointing out - will fix immediately!

Comment: Don't use `Response.Write` in webforms: you can't control where on the page it writes to (it's usually *before* the page is generated, so before it's starttag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, you need to call your `createString()` method. In your first block of code (static void main), `xstring` is a **variable**. In the `createString()` method, it is a **parameter**. These are different things, and giving them the same name will not automatically call the method for you. (Incidentally, your *parameter* `xstring` could have almost any different name, and it would work exactly the same.)

Therefore, in order for your code to work, you need to pass your variable `xstring` to the function `createString()` as a parameter, like so:

```
static void main()
    {
        SecondClass b = new SecondClass();
        b.x = 10;
        string xstring = (b.x.ToString());
        createString(xstring);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A web site does not execute your `Main()` method, that's for applications only. And like [@Marton indicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27038618/is-there-something-wrong-with-my-accessibility/27038667#comment42596842_27038618), this code does not call `createString()` either.